# What are these small icons next to app?

Tags: applications, app-icons

[image]

I've seen this home screen on internet and I wanted to know what are the small bars and triangles next to the app's icons ?

Comment: What launcher are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This comes from Action Launcher 3.

Those icons are features of the launcher called  *Shutters* and *Covers*. As described [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/12/11/hands-on-the-completely-redesigned-action-launcher-3-from-chris-lacy-makes-your-home-screen-material/),

> Both Shutters and Covers are indicated by small shapes in the corner
>   of your icons.

See corresponding screenshot:

[image]

The equals sign means there's a *widget* associated with the app and you can swipe up on the icon to display its widget in a popup folder window. These are "Shutters"

Another main feature is "Covers" which is similar. It is basically just *folders*, but when you tap the icon it launches the first app instead of opening the folder. To open the folder you swipe up.

Source:

[Do you use a launcher other than Nova or Google? Why do you think it is better?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3efzv0/do_you_use_a_launcher_other_than_nova_or_google/)

**Update**

Action launcher received a major update sometime ago, and has been renamed just Action Launcher (the 3 dropped).

According to [Android Authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/action-launcher-drops-3-name-part-big-update-782399/),

> Not only does it have a bunch of new features, it also includes a new
>   logo for the app and a new name... The app is dropping the “3” part of
>   its name and it will simply be called Action Launcher from now on.

Additionally you'll notice the shutters and covers have a new polished design with smoother edges, than previously before.

[image]

Comment: I think it is the new `O`